# Dynamic SQL query text

Tags: postgresql

hello can someone tell me what I am messing up,I get error on When clause in the first SELECT ,here is my code I have written I have updated it :

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_results() RETURNS VOID AS
  $BODY$
  DECLARE
  r    RECORD;
   BEGIN


    FOR r IN (SELECT 'CREATE TRIGGER ' || tab_name|| '_if_modified_trg AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON  ' || tab_name|| ' FOR EACH ROW WHEN (session_user <> ''source1'' OR (session_user = ''source1'' AND '|| tab_name ||' IN (SELECT*FROM table_names) ))
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func(); '
      AS trigger_creation_query
    FROM (
    SELECT  table_name as tab_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema='public'
    AND table_type != 'VIEW'

     )  AS foo WHERE tab_name||'_if_modified_trg' NOT IN (SELECT tgname from pg_trigger where not tgisinternal))


 LOOP


  EXECUTE r.trigger_creation_query;


END LOOP;


END
$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
 SELECT * FROM get_all_results();
```

Comment: What error do you get there? The loop works for me, but the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement looks syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have updated the code,now I get error that :  cannot use subquery in trigger WHEN condition

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html

> In FOR EACH ROW triggers, the WHEN condition can refer to columns of the old and/or new row values by writing OLD.column_name or NEW.column_name respectively.

This means you can not use subselects in trigger conditions. At least not in row triggers.